# How to download the schema of a postgres database on google cloud sql?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, pg-dump

I'm trying to use `pg_dump -s`, but I don't know how to connect.

The manpage gives these connection options:

```
  -d, --dbname=DBNAME      database to dump
  -h, --host=HOSTNAME      database server host or socket directory
  -p, --port=PORT          database server port number
```

How do I find out this data for google sql cloud?

One attempt:

```
pg_dump -s -h=IPADDRESS -d=postgres
```

Leads to this error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "" failed: invalid connection option ""
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting#posgressqldump) you can find a guide on how to export data from your GCP console user interface. This operation executes the "pg_dump" command in the backend and you do not need to worry about setting any parameters.

You can also do the export to a GCS storage bucket using gcloud commands :

```
  gsutil mb -p [PROJECT_NAME] -l [LOCATION_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]


  gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]


  gsutil acl ch -u [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS]:W gs://[BUCKET_NAME]


  gcloud sql export sql [INSTANCE_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/sqldumpfile.gz \
                          --database=[DATABASE_NAME]


  gsutil acl ch -d [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

If you want to do this operation manually for a database which is **not** managed by Cloud SQL you can do it using the pg_dump command:

`pg_dump -U [USERNAME] --format=plain --no-owner --no-acl [DATABASE_NAME] \
    | sed -E 's/(DROP|CREATE|COMMENT ON) EXTENSION/-- \1 EXTENSION/g' > [SQL_FILE].sql`

Note that this command won't work on a Cloud SQL instance, because for some of the flags you need the SUPERUSER role.

**EDIT**:

You can also export data with a curl, using [the Cloud SQL API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting). In case you want the schema only, in your request body you should add the property `"schemaOnly": true`. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export#request) you can find more details about how to build your request.

Comment: The gcloud guide doesn't explain how to get only the schema, the pg_dump command doesn't include connection options.

Comment: I have edited the answer with an alternative for exporting only the schema.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @/home/donn/tmp/gcp_sql_export_request.json \
https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/my-project-id/instances/my-postgres-db/export
```

Where the file `gcp_sql_export_request.json` contains:

```
{
 "exportContext":
   {
      "fileType": "SQL",
      "uri": "gs://my-bucket/tmp/donn_syslogdb_dump.sql",
      "databases": ["mydatabase"],
      "sqlExportOptions": {
        "schemaOnly": true
      },
      "offload": true
    }
}
```

offload=true may not be necessary, but I did it just to be safe (in case the operation screwed-up and ran a long time).

Ensure you grant `storage.objectAdmin` permissions (GCS bucket) to the service account that is tied to the database.

Find the service account tied to the db instance-id:

```
$ gcloud sql instances describe my-postgres-db | grep serviceAccountEmailAddress
serviceAccountEmailAddress: xxx123456789-xxxxxx@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```